# Is Javascript Testing Framework about testing javascript code or using javascript to test any application written in some other programming language?

Tags: javascript, cucumber

Is Javascript Testing Framework about testing javascript code or using javascript to test any application written in some other programming language?

Cucumber is an example of javascript Testing Framework but we can use Java to test any non-javascript functionality of an application. So in this case Javascript is not involved anywhere but still Cucumber is called Javascript Testing Framework, why?

Comment: I'm confused with the term "Javascript Testing Framework" as the word Javascript has been used hence is it about using Javascript to test or is it about testing javascript application or functionality using any language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a Javascript testing framework to verify Javascript, then it is about testing javascript.

If you use a Javascript testing framework to test an application from the outside, then it is about testing an application without consideration of the programming language the application is implemented in.

It all depends on your perspective.

You can't use a Javascript testing framework to test Java or c# code. It isn't possible to instantiate a native object and work with it using Javascript.

You are interested in reading the [blog post](https://cucumber.io/blog/2014/03/03/the-worlds-most-misunderstood-collaboration-tool) Aslak Hellesøy, the creator of Cucumber, wrote a couple of years ago about Cucumber as a testing tool. Short spoiler, Cucumber isn't about testing.

Comment: Thanks @thomas-sundberg